# adding the folder name to a file using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, directory, renaming

I am trying to use a batch file to add the folder name to a file. I want to use the folder name from 1 folder up. I have, from here and other sources :

```
for %%* in (..) do set CurrDirName=%%~n*

echo %CurrDirName%

set strPrefix=%CurrDirName%

for %%a in (*) do rename "%%a" "%CurrDirName%_%%a"
```

The correct folder name is being added but it is caught in an endless loop of adding it until the file names are too long for the os. I am very new to this, having started today, so any help would be much appreciated and if you reply like talking to an idiot you will not be far off! Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is a known bug/feature of the `for` command.  The file list that the for loop generates is dynamic, meaning that files modified in the loop will be re-added to the list causing an infinite loop.

Use the `dir` command to generate a static file list.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b *') do rename "%%A" "%CurrDirName%_%%A"
```

See [`dir /?`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) for all the options.

Welcome to the world of Batch scripting. **`:)`**

Comment: +1, I'm not sure it is technically a FOR bug. But it certainly is a design limitation.

Comment: imo it's not a bug; it's more somewhat like a historical artifact from the FCB's in CP/M.

Comment: @Endoro and @dbenham  I agree with your comments. **`:)`**  It is not specifically an issue with the `for` command, however, the general batch user is not going to care about the [FCB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_control_block) of old; just how the commands seem to behave when used.  So my goal was to [KIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).  Thank you, and if either of you have a link to a more detailed explanation of the underlying file system that you would like to post in adjunction to this, please do.  It would be a great reference to have.